# I can't get MXMLC to work on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-flex, ubuntu, mxmlc

Okay, I downloaded the Flex 4 SDK from Adobe and extracted the contents to `~/Documents/flex4_sdk`.

Now I have the following simple MXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- usingas/StatementSyntax.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Label id="label1"/>

</mx:Application>
```

When I compile it with `mxmlc /path/to/file.mxml`, I get:

> Loading configuration file ~/Documents/flex4_sdk/frameworks/flex-config.xml
>   /path/to/file.mxml (38642 bytes)

However, the resultant SWF file is blank. (Basically just a white canvas.)

Comment: That code should result in a blank SWF.  BTW: The Flex 4 SDK works fine for me on Ubuntu 10.04 with Sun's Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results if I Try to compile similar code using Flash Builder on Windows.

Try to give the label a value so there is actual a visual piece on your application

```
<mx:Label id="label1" text="Label1"/>
```

If at all possible I strongly recommend using the Flex 4 spark Application instead of the old mx approach.  Your app might look like this:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Label text="label1" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: The spark Application thing doesn't work, I'm afraid. Neither does adding the text property to the label.

Comment: Bizarre is all I Can say.  Be sure to file a bug at bugs.adobe.com